# How to import components into a Vue.JS plugin component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, plugins, vue-component

### Situation

I'm trying to create a Vue.JS plugin to package some components which I need to use in multiple projects.

In this plugin, I created a component called "ComponentA" which I chose to expose globally.

This is my ComponentA definition :

```js
<template>
  <ComponentB ref="componentB">
    <!-- some DOM Elements -->
    <ComponentC someparams ref="componentC"></ComponentC>
  </ComponentB>
</template>

<script>
import { ComponentB } from "component-b-lib";
import { ComponentC } from "component-c-lib";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";

export default {
  name: 'ComponentA',
  components: {
    ComponentB,
    ComponentC
  },
  // propos and methods
}
</script>

<style lang="scss"></style>
```

As you can see, I use 2 others components in ComponentA definition : ComponentB and Component, both coming from different libraries. I added a package.json file in my plugin directory :

```js
{
  "name": "my-plugin",
  "description": "My Plugin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "author": {
    "name": "me",
    "email": "me@me.me"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "component-b-lib": "file:plugins/component-b.tgz",
    "component-c-lib": "file:plugins/component-c.tgz",
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "main": "my-plugin.js"
}
```

(I specify that I launched the npm install).

This is the main file of my plugin (my-plugin.js) :

```js
import ComponentA from "./components/ComponentA.vue";

const MyPlugin = {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    install(Vue, options) {
        Vue.component(ComponentA.name, ComponentA);
    }
};

export default MyPlugin;
```

This is how I include my plugin in main.js file of my App (this is a temporary solution during the development phase, I will use npm afterwards) :

```js
import MyPlugin from "../plugins/my-plugin";

createApp(App).use(FpevVueLayout).mount('#app')
```

Then, inside one of my main app component, this is how I included my ComponentA :

```js
<template>
    <ComponentA someparams/>
</template>
```

Because ComponentA is globally referenced, it is perfectly recognized.

### Problem

The problem is that ComponentB and ComponentC, used in ComponentA template, are not referenced, and I don't understand why. This is the DOM of ComponentA content :

```html
<component-b data-v-17906dc2=""><component-c myparams=...></component-c></component-b></div>
```

It looks like the two referenced components are treated as simple DOM elements, not as Vue components.

I think that is coming from my dependency references (package.json of my plugin), which are not used when referencing my plugin directly from main.js.

Maybe this is not the right approach, do you please have any tips/ideas about my problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem could be that you're importing the components as objects (i.e., named exports), not as default exports, but the components may be default exports from the libraries. This depends on how the components are exported in their respective libraries. try:
`import ComponentB from "component-b-lib";`
`import ComponentC from "component-c-lib";`

Comment: @Insula Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried your solution but still the same behavior in my web page.